# Mongodb data store parameter on Opengeo Suite 4.1.1

Tags: geoserver, boundless-suite, mongodb

I'm using Opengeo Suite 4.1.1 with built in Mongodb data store plugin on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Windows 8.0. Geoserver 2.5 snapshot and Mongodb 2.6 versions are used here.

I was about to try [Mapping #WorldCup with OpenGeo Suite and MongoDB](http://boundlessgeo.com/2014/06/mapping-worldcup-opengeo-suite-mongodb/) by using my own spatial data, but when I create new data store there was an error message as its shown below. I also don't set any user or password on Mongodb before.
[image: error message]

I can't figure out what is the problem and how to solve it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. The error was the result of a malformed uri at the schema_store. Please, note the third slash in the example.

**schema_store *** :
file://**/**path/to/store

Alternatively, I see you have not included a port number in the data_store. This could also give an error.

**data_store *** :
mongodb://localhost:27017/test

Comment: for schema_store: this is an example for the path: file:///C:/apache-tomcat-9.0.37/webapps/geoserver/data/workspaces/test